# Centralised infinite carousel with indeterminate edge items

Tags: javascript, carousel, infinite, swiper.js

I'm either looking for some theory code or suitable JavaScript library to accomplish the following:

See diagram: http://cl.ly/image/2R3P28363U27

Requirements:

- Circular/infinite
- Not flicker the DOM during cloning on any visible edge items
- The current item must be centralised
- Items can be a fixed width (because it's a fixed width site)
- Carousel only needs to move left/right by one item at a time (no pagination necessary)

I've seen plenty of instances of carousels which offer some of these features, but not all. Can anyone send me in the right direction?

Side note: I've noticed that iDangerous Swiper has both 'centeredItems' and 'loop' options, both which seem to be ideal, but they don't work together.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd look into using CSS3 transitions, they give much 'smoother' scrolling.

Comment: I don't mean a flicker in performance, I mean that some infinite carousels do a last-minute change in the DOM order to mimick the infinite appearance.